# WPF C# DataBinding List

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to make a custom style for a listbox in Visual C# using WPF using data-binding.

I have the following class:

```
public class Page
{
    public readonly DateTime Sent;
    public readonly string PagerID;
    public readonly string Message;
    public readonly string Status;

    private Page(DateTime sent, string pagerID, string message, string status)
    {
        Sent = sent;
        PagerID = pagerID;
        Message = message;
        Status = status;
    }

    public static List<Page> GetPages()
    {
        ...
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Sent + ": " + PagerID + " - " + Message;
    }
}
```

And the following WPF .xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="KentBox.utilities.RecentPages"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KentBox.utilities"
        Title="RecentPages" Height="640" Width="480">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Name="Provider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Page}" MethodName="GetRecentPages" />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</Window>
```

If I change TextBlock Text to ="{Binding}" instead of {Binding Message}, I can get the pages to show up with the overridden ToString() contents.

I can't figure out how to make the Binding display only the Message portion of the page. Visual Studio tells me

> Cannot resolve property 'Message' in data context of type 'System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider'

I can't figure out how to change the type of said data context. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Message needs to be a public property.  It needs to have a get.

Comment: You can only bind Propertys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message needs to be a public property. It needs to have a get.

```
public string Message { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. It works now, thanks!